# Problem running i.gensigset in Grass. Any ideas?

Tags: grass-gis, remote-sensing, classification

It just returns `ERROR: Unable to create signature file`.  It doesn't say why... Anyone had this before and found a solution?

Comment: A few more details would be needed. For example, the output of g.region -p

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved it by giving the group name without the @permanent part.

Take a look at the /yourlocation/permanent/group folder. You may find there a "yourgroup" folder and a folder "yourgroup@permanent". So take care when you give parameters to i.gensigset so that when you give the name of group you omit the @permanent.

Comment: Please submit this as a bug to http://grass.osgeo.org/bugtracking/