# Empty signature file after i.gensig in GRASS

Tags: grass-gis, classification

I'm trying to make a supervised classification in Grass 6.4.3 under Linuxmint 16.

After digitizing the training areas, I transformed them from vector to raster.
Then I've done the following:
just in case:
`g.region rast=train_area_2013_03_05_raster@PERMANENT,2013_03_05_toar4@PERMANENT`

then

`i.group group=group subgroup=sub_group input=2013_03_05_toar4@PERMANENT,2013_03_05_toar5@PERMANENT,2013_03_05_toar3@PERMANENT`

and

`i.gensig trainingmap=train_area_2013_03_05_raster@PERMANENT group=group@PERMANENT subgroup=sub_group signaturefile=superv_class`

but the resulting signature file, only contains one character: "#".

The output of i.gensig in the console is the following:

```
Finding training classes...
3 classes found
Calculating class means...
Calculating class covariance matrices...
Signature 1 not invertible
Signature 2 not invertible
Signature 3 not invertible
i.gensig complete.
```

Obviously if I try:
`i.maxlik group=group@PERMANENT subgroup=sub_group sigfile=superv_class class=results_class`

I obtain the following error message:

`ERROR: Unable to read signature file <superv_class>`

I've been searching, but I couldn't find the solution.

I've tried: this [Problem running i.gensigset in Grass. Any ideas?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11933/problem-running-i-gensigset-in-grass-any-ideas)

My problem is similar to this: [i.maxlik cannot read i.class output signature file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41418/i-maxlik-cannot-read-i-class-output-signature-file). But here, there's no solution suggested. As in this case, I also used `i.cluster` to generate an unsupervised signature file and `i.maxlik` reads this perfectly well.

[Here](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/grass-user/2010-April/055821.html) there's another similar question, but again, with no solution...

What does `Signature X not invertible` means?

Any idea?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you found a solution to your question, why not post it as an answer instead of an edit?

Answer (score 1):

Joseph, you're right. Here is the solution to MY problem. 
May be someone could add some more detail, but this is how I solved it:

- The region of my interest was about a quarter of the original image so, I clipped the Landsat image to a smaller size, leaving out a big region in which I'm not interested BEFORE start classifying (I was planning to do it at the end of the process).
- I re-digitized the training areas paying attention to, as someone told me: "Training areas should be big enough to contain a significant number of pixels, but small enough to be homogeneous".
- After that, I've done all the process (v.to.rast, i.gensig, i.maxlik) again, and with no problems!
- Besides the size of the image and that I had all the training areas in a small region of it, I think that my previous digitized training-areas weren't too small, but most probably, they weren't homogeneous.